# Every snap installed executable getting ibudev.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: snap, libraries, kubernetes

Every time that i run any snap installed app, i'm getting this message:

/snap/core/9066/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object

in this case i've used `kubectl` command. Installed by:

`snap install kubectl --classic`

Comment: Why the `14.04` tag?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]